# Firebase Authentication handler doesn't get called

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I am trying to authenticate users through Firebase and use their assigned userIDs to store profile pictures. Here in the code I have assigned userID with default nil in the beginning of class, and am reassigning to fetched result after a user is created. However, when I try to access userID from a few lines below I get a nil exception, that is the userID never got changed. After debugging I realized that this is because the handler never gets called, however I have no idea why. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Update, no single callback function is executed. I have a couple of anonymous function like the one in the picture, and none are being called

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not keeping the reference for the `auth` object and this is why your call back closure is not being called. It's hard to check why is not being called without more context, but maybe you could give it a try.

```swift
class YourCalss {
  private let auth = Auth.auth()

  func yourMethod() {
    auth.createUser(withEmail: ..., password: ...)
  }
}
```

Give it a shot. I hope this could somehow helpful :)

Comment: I tried keep a reference of auth, but that didn't really change anything. Thanks anyway.